# How to set a background image to a Grid in xamarin.forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, grid, background-image

I want to set a background image to my `Grid` in code behind. I found in internet that we can do using XAML like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="Pages.PhotoPage">
    <Grid >
        <Image Source="background.png" Aspect="AspectFit" />
        <!-- Place here the rest of the layout for the page. -->
    </Grid >
```

But how can I set this in code behind. I cannot see any`Image` or `BackgroundImage` property for `Grid`. Please help me. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can just create an empty `Image` element in the `Grid` and set it.

```
<Grid>
    <Image x:Name="BackgroundImage" Aspect="AspectFit" />
    <!-- Place here the rest of the layout for the page. -->
</Grid>
```

And now set it in code:

```
backgroundImage.Source = ...;
```

If you are building the whole UI in code, you can do this as well:

```
var myGrid = new Grid();
var backgroundImage = new Image();
backgroundImage.Source = ...;
myGrid.Children.Add( backgroundImage );
```

If your `Grid` has multiple rows and columns, you will want to set the `Grid.ColumnSpan` and `Grid.RowSpan` properties on the image to make it span the whole grid.